# cmake clang-tidy (or other script) as custom target

Tags: cmake, clang, target, lint, clang-tidy

I am trying to create a custom cmake target for clang-tidy, to lint my project. The source folder looks something like this:

```
src/scripts/run-clang-tidy.py
src/.clang-tidy
src/...
```

So far my plan was to copy both these files to the build directory with a custom command:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT run-clang-tidy.py .clang-tidy
    COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/run-clang-tidy.py ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.clang-tidy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

I now want to call `run-clang-tidy.py` in the build directory (which should be the working directory), with a custom target, so that I can just call:

```
make lint
```

Which should run the checks specified in `.clang-tidy`.

For this script to work, it also needs the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` option. I try to set it with the following command, but it does not recognize it:

```
add_definitions(-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON)
```

How would the call to `add_custom_target` look like?

Comment: CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS is a CMake variable. When set to ON it generates a file:  "compile_commands.json" which clang tools can use. It is not a compiler preprocessor macro. tl;dr: `set (CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since CMake 3.6, native integration of `clang-tidy` is implemented [[1](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html), [2](http://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2016-April/028215.html)].  Mechanics are similar to `include-what-you-use` integration that was there since CMake 3.3 [[3](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_LANG_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE.html)].

Comment: It looks like this only works for makefile and ninja generators and doesn't work for XCode or Visual Studio.  So, not as helpful as I'd hoped.

Answer (score 12):

I can suggest another way to do, which do not require an extra Python script.

First of all, I wanted to integrate `clang-tidy` and `clang-format` in custom CMake rules, so I first generated `.clang-tidy` and `.clang-format` files which were located at the root directory of the project.

### Generating the configuration files

To generate `.clang-tidy`, first find the suitable options for your project and then, just do:

```
$> clang-tidy <source-files> -dump-config <tidy-options> -- <compile-options> > .clang-tidy
```

Similarly for `clang-format` you may start with a default style using the `-style=xxx` option, and dump it. For example, starting with the LLVM style:

```
$> clang-format -style=LLVM -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Then, edit it and configure it properly as you wish. It should looks like that:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: true
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BinPackParameters: true
BinPackArguments: true
ColumnLimit:     80
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
DerivePointerAlignment: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Right
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
Standard:        Cpp11
IndentWidth:     2
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
DisableFormat:   false
...
```

### Creating the custom CMake rule

CMake allow to define custom rules in a very simple way, you just have to write a set of CMake commands in a file with a call to the `add_custom_target()` procedure and, then, include it in your `CMakeList.txt` file. This is what we will do, we first create a `cmake/clang-dev-tools.cmake` file at the root of your project:

```
# Additional target to perform clang-format/clang-tidy run
# Requires clang-format and clang-tidy

# Get all project files
file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES *.cpp *.hpp)

add_custom_target(
        clang-format
        COMMAND /usr/bin/clang-format
        -style=file
        -i
        ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
)

add_custom_target(
        clang-tidy
        COMMAND /usr/bin/clang-tidy
        ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
        -config=''
        --
        -std=c++11
        ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
)
```

Then, edit you `CMakeLists.txt` and add:

```
# Including extra cmake rules
include(cmake/clang-dev-tools.cmake)
```

Then, once the build-system regenerated, you should be able to run `make clang-tidy` and `make clang-format`.

Comment: This mostly works but it won't detect my include directories

Comment: Had same issue, there is a parameter missing in the cmake rule, it should be `-I${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}` instead of `${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}`

Answer (score 8):

The documentation mentioned by [Alexander Shukaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743860/alexander-shukaev) is a bit short on details, so I'm adding an example. The formatting of the warning strings makes IDEs think the clang-tidy results are compiler warnings and will mark the source code. Also, it runs each file in parallel after its object file has been created.

```
if ( CMAKE_VERSION GREATER "3.5" )
  set(ENABLE_CLANG_TIDY OFF CACHE BOOL "Add clang-tidy automatically to builds")
  if (ENABLE_CLANG_TIDY)
    find_program (CLANG_TIDY_EXE NAMES "clang-tidy" PATHS /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin )
    if (CLANG_TIDY_EXE)
      message(STATUS "clang-tidy found: ${CLANG_TIDY_EXE}")
      set(CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS "-*,modernize-*")
      set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_EXE};-checks=${CLANG_TIDY_CHECKS};-header-filter='${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*'"
        CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    else()
      message(AUTHOR_WARNING "clang-tidy not found!")
      set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "" CACHE STRING "" FORCE) # delete it
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
```

The only problems I've had with this is that it still checks automatically generated `moc_*.cxx` files and the usual annoyances of warnings from code in an [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: The if statement should be replaced by "if ( CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "3.5" )", otherwise cmake 3.10 and higher will not pass.

Answer (score 3):

`add_definitions` set *CMake* variable, available only configuration stage. If you want to set *environment* variable for command being executed at build stage, use appropriate shell mechanism with `COMMAND` keyword:

```
add_custom_target(lint
    COMMAND CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON python run-clang-tidy.py
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/run-clang-tidy.py
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/.clang-tidy
```

Everything specified for `COMMAND` keyword will be interpreted by the shell "as is" (after interpretation of CMake, which is no-op here).

Comment: For copying the files I guess i can use the ``file(...)`` command?

Comment: Your original `add_sustom_command()` seems to copy files correctly. But if you want, you may use `file(...)` command for that purpose.

Comment: I think the ``file`` command would be more portable? Or should I rather use ``cmake -E``?

Comment: Yes, `file` command is more portable, than `cp`. `cmake -E` shell command is also portable. But, the way for specify environment variable in my answer is already reduce portability (`a=1 do_something` does not work on Windows). If you limit you project usage to Linux (or Unix-like OS'es) , it is OK to use `cp` (and it is fast). If you want your project to work under Windows, you need to set environent variable in Windows-specific way.