# How to run Clang-based tool as a separate CMake target

Tags: cmake

I have written a Clang-based tool and I want to run it on existing CMake executable target. I want this to be **a separate** Makefile target, so I can run it without builiding exe target.

There is a solution to run it during exe target build (described in [cmake clang-tidy (or other script) as custom target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280717/cmake-clang-tidy-or-other-script-as-custom-target))

```
set(CLANG_TIDY_EXE  ${MY_CLANG_BASED_TOOL} )
set(DO_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_EXE}" " --my-additional-options")

set_target_properties(
        my_exe_target PROPERTIES
        CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${DO_CLANG_TIDY}"
)
```

CMake runs my tool during my_exe_target build. In build log I see:

```
...    
cmake -E __run_co_compile --tidy=my_tool --source=main.cpp -- ..
```

But is it possible to create a separate target?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), e.g. (adjust according to your vars and other needs):

```
add_custom_target(tidyup
    COMMAND ${DO_CLANG_TIDY} [...] ${SOURCES}
   DEPENDS [...]
   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

---

**edit** (to address OP question):

A good starting point is to search for `__run_co_compile` and try to recreate the command from the `Makefile` rule (if your generator is `make`). There's no "automatic" propagation of the attributes, because a custom target or command can be anything. You could use the corresponding `cmake` [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) (e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, etc) or target [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) (e.g. `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`) to emulate that.

Comment: But how can I propagate all exe target properties (include paths, defines etc) to custom command?

Comment: __run_co_compile is in cmake c++ sources. So it looks like the only option is to fork CMake and implement extension in c++.

Comment: @random that's definitely not the way, I think you misundestood me. `__run_co_compile` is the name to search for (e.g. `grep`) for convenience inside the generate `Makefile`. You can use that line to recreate the command using `add_custom_target`.

Comment: It is not possible, because transitively inherited flags from linked libraries are not available during scan of CMakeLists. Probably there is a way using generator expressions...

Comment: @random Well, the initial question never mentioned the exact requirements for the `clang-tidy`-like tool. Second, if those libraries are imported as `cmake` modules, those flags should be available in the `IMPORTED`-related properties for the corresponding imported targets. Lastly, you might be able to create a script template (`.in`) that could use `configure_file` plus whatever tool to extract those flags (e.g. `pkg-config`) and actually run that from the build directory once configuration is done.